# Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, connection, update

I have recently (past 24 hours) noticed the above message when logging into a headless server over WAN via ssh.

When I try to apt-get update the server, I get "Failed to fetch ... Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'"

It runs on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Based on comments below, I have attempted to determine whether the issue is connectivity, or DNS related.

Since first issue was connecting to changelogs.ubutu.com, I ran ping changelogs.ubuntu.com, which worked.

What else could be causing this, and how can it be resolved?

EDIT: The issue has resolve spontaneously, as described below.

Comment: What options did you explore? What were the results? The message is pretty clear as to what the issue is.

Comment: I edited post above to outline what I attempted. Given that connection is ok, this is further confusing.

Comment: You have trouble resolving `ca.archive.ubuntu.com`, to test it you ping `changelogs.ubuntu.com` and then you conclude it's not a DNS issue? Interesting.

Comment: Hi Gerald. Edited post above to explain better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is a DNS issue rather than network connectivity.

Can you ping a public IP, for example:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

If that is successful, next try:

```
nslookup www.google.com
```

If that fails, then it is likely a DNS problem and can work towards resolving it.

Comment: Thanks Derrick Johnson. I ran the ping from the actual hostname I was having issues with, and it worked. Now, looking into other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

To update, I just ran sudo apt-get update again, and it worked without issue.

I did not modify any files, only ran tests described in original post.

Odd.